# Visual Studio 2012 Code Snippets foreach

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to auto-populate an iteration, after collection has been made in Visual studio? This is what i want to happen after typing foreach after collection.

```
var names = new List<string>();
foreach(name in names)
{

}

var persons = new List<string>();
foreach(person in persons)
{

}
```

Read the article on how to create custom snippets in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx but does not show conditional options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Visual Studio can do this by itself (at least not in version 2012). You can however check out [**Resharper**](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which can guess template placeholders [based on the context](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Templates__Applying_Templates__Creating_Source_Code_Using_Live_Templates.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not correct,
First you don't assign the `name` and `person` the type(such as `var` or `string`)

```
var names = new List<string>();
foreach(var name in names)
{

}

var persons = new List<string>();

foreach(var person in persons)
{

}
```

Try This [Output](https://repl.it/@timsky/ListForEach)